# ¿Se puede redefinir un objeto de una clase?

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo una clase Matriz que recibe dos parámetros obligatorios: el nº de filas y de columnas. Y quiero reutilizar un objeto e ir cambiándole el nº de filas y columnas, algo así:

```
for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
   Matriz M(i, i);
   //Hacer algo con la matriz
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacerlo? He buscado para hacerlo con punteros y usando *new* y *delete* pero no me queda claro de cómo pasar los argumentos obligatorios a cada matriz.

Comment: Pues dependiendo del diseño de la clase será posible o no... pero sin esa información es difícil saberlo

Comment: Deberias darnos mas informacion sobre como esta implementada esa clase matriz. En un principio practicamente cualqueir cosa es posible si estamos hablando de algo enteramente hecho por uno mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si esa clase matriz es definida por ti, podrías tener dos métodos de asignación a las propiedades de columnas y filas:

```
public class Matriz{
  private int col;
  private int fil;

  public int col{
     set{col = value;}
  }

  public int fil{
     set{fil = value;}
  }
}
```

Luego de ello sí podrías reutilizar un mismo objeto, modificando los valores de las propiedades:

```
Matriz M = new Matriz();
for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
   M.col = i;
   M.fil = i;
   //Hacer algo con la matriz
}
```

Comment: ¿ Eso que lenguaje es ?

Comment: @Trauma es c#. Desde luego ni es c++ ni tampoco compatible con el mismo. Además no ha tenido en cuenta la memoria dinámica asociada a la matriz

Comment: y porque fue aceptada la respuesta? no hay ninguna matriz ahi.. hay un objeto con 2 propiedades